# Keep every nth element of a conduit stream

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm using Conduit to parse some data in a stream-like manner. At some point in the stream I require every 12th element. Is there a convenient way to do this?

I'm currently explicitly waiting for 12 elements just to return the first element:

```
get12th :: Monad m => Conduit Int m Int
get12th = loop
  where
    loop = do
        v1 <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        _ <- await
        case v1 of
            Nothing -> return ()
            Just x -> do
              yield x >> loop
```

It does work, but I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Also, you end up waiting for a bunch more elements before you deliver the current one (`v1 <- await` would be better at the bottom - your trampoline call can handle the fact you should start with an `await`)

Comment: @Alec I understand what you're saying and I have a solution in mind. However, I don't see how moving `v1 <- await` to the bottom solves the problem.

Comment: Here, you wait an extra 11 elements before sending the next element (which you received 11 elements ago!). By moving `v1 <- await`, you will send `v1` as soon as you get it.

Comment: @Alec I still don't see how moving the `v1 <- await` solves the problem. There is no point in doing anything until you've gotten `v1` and yielded it. That's why I'm now waiting for `v1`. Once I've gotten it, I immediately yield it, wait for 11 more values and then loop again. But it doesn't really matter since this seems to add a reasonable performance penalty.

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden, what you describe is not the same as your code.  In the code you've posted, you do not "immediately yield it".  You yield it after a bunch more `await`s.  Maybe you posted an older version of your code?

Comment: @luqui Yes, what I'm describing here is not in the question. I haven't added it since I don't regard it as being a good solution (due to the performance penalty).

Comment: @luqui I seem to be wrong about the performance penalty it imposes. I've ran my tests again and it seems to be beneficial to performance.

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden I suggest you post the solution you edited into your question as an answer.

Comment: @duplode I probably will. I just didn't want to take credit for other people's contributions.

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden Don't worry; you gave proper credit to the comments which inspired your solution, and so no one will begrudge you for it.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for making the answer yourself, good call!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Alec, Chad Gilbert and Michael Snoyman, I've come to the following solution:

```
get12th :: Monad m => Conduit Int m Int
get12th = loop
  where loop = do
          v <- await
          case v of
            Just x  -> yield x >> CL.drop 11 >> loop
            Nothing -> return ()
```

This solution uses the `drop` function to get rid of the duplicate awaits. It yields the first value as soon as it receives it, before waiting for the other values.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`replicateM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM_) to get rid of those duplicate `await` lines.

```hs
v1 <- await
replicateM_ 11 await
case v1 of
   ...
```

Comment: The [`drop` function](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.13/conduit-1.2.8/Data-Conduit-List.html#v:drop) is probably relevant.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Good point! Drop is probably more efficient since it doesn't have to hold values in memory. Though I'm not sure whether `replicateM_ 11 await` does.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman You seem to be correct. The `drop` function seems to be the most efficient. Replacing the duplicate `await`s with `replicateM_ 11 await` seems to have a (ever so slightly) negative impact on performance. Replacing `replicateM_11` with `Data.Conduit.List.drop 11` seems to noticeably increase performance.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Could you add using the `drop` function instead of `replicateM_` as an answer so I can accept it?